# How does (?=[A-Z]) regex work with split() function?

Tags: regex

I tried

```
var str = "thisIsATest";

var newStr = str.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);

console.log(newStr);
```

The result came out as I wanted:

```
['this', 'Is', 'A', 'Test']
```

but the function of

```
?= is  

x(?=y)
```

Matches x only if x is followed by y.

So shouldn't split happen at the last letter of each word.

```
['thi', 'I', '', 'Test']
```

something like this... or not .

since if i do `split(' ');` it will split at every "space"

Comment: `Matches x only if x is followed by y` In your example `x` is an empty match and `y` is an uppercase letter.

Comment: @anubhava oh okay. Since I didn't specify a character for `x`, it will just match in front of any uppercase? Is that correct?

Comment: It will match at any _position_ in the string where the next character is an uppercase.  This is how a lookahead works.

Comment: Okay. Thanks, guys! :D

Answer (score 0):

When you try to split, don't imagine that it looks at each character. Instead, try to imagine that it works kind of a like a cursor, going from:

```
|thisIsATest
```

to:

```
thisIsATest|
```

The reason why it works like a cursor is because you are telling it to match every empty string `""`, so obviously, you only need to consider the stuff "between" the characters.

Each time it moves, `?=` tells it to look at the characters ahead, without moving ahead. If the characters ahead matches `[A-Z]`. If it matches, split the string!

Here:

```
this|IsATest
```

the character after the cursor is `I`, so it matches and it splits.

It also splits at the following positions:

```
thisIs|ATest
thisIsA|Test
```